# When extending a class, use an injected object of that class

Tags: polymorphism

*I don't know the technical terms for the title, so please bear with me.*

In **O**bject **O**riented **P**rogramming it is a common feature to have polymorphism
One Object is another while acting maybe different

This is a cool idea,
but my instructor told me to not use `extend`,

I figured his reasoning for that rule is since extending couples a class deeply with its parent class,
while also being unable to manufacture the upper class separately.

I will retell the sentence with code:

```
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent
{
    //constructor
    public Child() {
        super();
        //equals
        //this = new Parent();
        //first: This functions is the Factory of a Parent Object
        //second: due to that Child knows exactly the Parent Class and is coupled with the Parent
    }
}
```

**What if we could**

```
//I add an Interface, so I can make a second Implementation of this Interface 
//and swap them if I want
interface ParentInterface {} 
class Parent implements ParentInterface {}
class Child extends ParentInterface
{
    public Child(ParentInterface parent) {
        super = parent; 
    }
}
```

Question:
Why can't we inject and extend an already given object?

Is something like this out there?

> -> if no
> Why isn't something like this out there?

Edit:
In the second Example:
The Child class is `extending` an implementation of `ParentInterface`
And the `super = parent;` means:
Instead of Child creating the parental class himself, he gets his `Parent` injected

Comment: Should that be `class Child implements` in the second snippet? Or what is `super = ...` supposed to do? Half of this resembles the so-called "Strategy pattern", but the other half I'm not sure how to parse, really.

Comment: The `Child` class should be `extending` an implementation of `ParentInterface`

Comment: @trentcl instead of Child creating the `parental class` himself, he gets his `Parent` injected

Comment: I'm only familiar with the `implements`/`extends` dichotomy from Java, and in that language classes cannot extend interfaces, only implement them. So I'm not sure what it means that `Child extends ParentInterface`. Surely it can't mean subclassing, because `ParentInterface` isn't a class.

Comment: @trentcl This is my Question, Why cant we inject and extend an already given object?

Comment: What would it mean to do that? What would the superclass of `Child` be? `Object`?

Comment: @trentcl
It **could** be `Parent`, 
but if the developer of this code decides to use a new  `Parent2` class, he could exchange the classes pretty quick. Thats the fascination of abstraction and my confusion over why this does not exist

Comment: [Don't signal your edits in text.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text)

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is what I am talking about. Composition instead of inheritance. Inheritance is such a cool feature. Why are we not using inheritance with my proposed approach? (injecting the parent class)

Comment: Classes cannot extend interfaces, so second example won't compile,

Comment: @TulainsCórdova i know. I speak from why not

Comment: To find out more about the "why not," do a Google search for "favor composition over inheritance."

Answer (score 0):

### Preliminary remark

The advice not to use `extend` is about preferring [composition over inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

It is grounded on the fact that there is often a misjudgment in the use of inheritance which appears to be a very strong and inflexible relationship between the child and its parent. Moreover, when you have a hammer in the hand, every problem looks like a nail, and when new to OOP, every problem tends to look like inheritance.

Now, this is a guidance and not a golden rule. If you use OOP and never apply inheritance, there must be something wrong as well.

### parents and child

You can always implement an existing object. That’s how dependency injection work.

The problem in your second snippet is that the child should not extend but implement the parent interface.

You may then very well inject a parent object. By the way if the child would offer “more” than the parent interface, you should define “more” as an additional child interface so that you could also have other children that implement the same interface.

The problem with the injection, is that you need to create two different objects, and moreover, the child would have to forward some calls to the parent.  So if the child is really a specialization of the parent (and stays this specialization throughout its lifetime) it may be more convenient to just extend the parent.

Comment: I'll use an example a had not long ago.  
I had a VO with data. The VO was for the Database (for the ORM Doctrine). 
I should give the object to the template engine and read out there. But I needed some special functions to process some of the values. So I wanted to extend the VO with some functions. To do so, I gave in the original VO into the constructor, deconstructed it there to pass all parameters into the parent creation, and added my functions to the Processing Object. If I had my example from above, I would have just Extended the Object, without the nasty passing of data.

Comment: Addendum to my prior comment; This is a poor excuse for my bad thinking. I get your Point. Just implement the Interface, implement this nasty passing of parameters. Programmers like me tend to hate nasty stuff and like to not write much code. I am still asking why this is not in modern languages. Am I the only one who thought of such an interaction??

Comment: @temporarymaintainerofthis one should always challenge one-self when laking such decision, whether you chose inheritance or composition. So, no, you’re not the only one. The thing is, that using inheritance just for reusing code or avoiding forward calls is rarely a good idea. however, if there is a real sub-typing/specialization relationship inherirance is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Classes cannot extend interfaces, so second example won't compile.

I see no problem for a class to have an injected member of the same type of the superclass.

If it serves the purpose you want to achieve, it's OK.  Do you seek to decorate the parent class without changing it?

Is this the decorator patter you need?

[image]

Comment: I do not need anything.  
I am asking, **Why is did language designers think, parent objects cant be injected**

Comment: @temporarymaintainerofthis Theres to clarify, what do you mean by parent objects: superclasses? Any object of any type can be injected inside another object, regardless of there being an inheritance relationship between the types or not.

Comment: yes i do mean super classes